# The angular way to handle this condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to display a Bootstrap modal if a certain value is empty or non-existent. The first solution I have is by passing the value to checkbox function:

```
// The object of functionality is to activate a 
// Bootstrap modal when the checkbox is checked, 
// but only if **{{part.ordered_from}}** is **empty**.

// OPTION 1 (Pass ordered_from into function):

<ul ng-repeat="part in partstoorder">

    <li>{{part.ordered_from}}</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" ng-change="change(ordered, {{part.id}}, {{part.vehicle_id}}, {{part.ordered_from}})"
        ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-model="ordered" name="part-ordered"  />
    <li>

</ul>

<script>

$scope.change = function(value, id, vehicle_id, ordered_from) {

    if (ordered_from && ordered_from != '') {


        $('#myModal').modal('show');

    }

};

</script>
```

The second option I have is to add an ID to the checkbox and a data attribute so I can locate the checkbox in the dom and get the value:

```
// OPTION 2 (find the value of a data-ordered_from property):

<ul ng-repeat="part in partstoorder">

    <li>{{part.ordered_from}}</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" ng-change="change(ordered, {{part.id}}, {{part.vehicle_id}})" id="ordered-from-checkbox-{{part.id}}"
        ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-model="ordered" name="part-ordered" data-ordered_from="{{part.ordered_from}}"  />
    <li>

</ul>

<script>

$scope.change = function(value, id, vehicle_id, ordered_from) {

    var orderedFrom = $('.ordered-from-checkbox-' + id).attr('data-ordered_from');

    if (orderedFrom && orderedFrom != '') {

        $('#myModal').modal('show');

    }

};

</script>
```

I am not happy with either of these solutions because I am sure the functionality could be achieved more elegantly using Angular. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Good advice: remove jQuery from project. For modal use UI Bootstrap.

Comment: Angular & Bootstrap use jQuery, it can't be removed. The only difference with UI Bootstrap – way to open `$modal.open(options)` which is best one, but not critical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first option is OK btw. I would like to improve your condition

```
<ul ng-repeat="part in partstoorder">
    <li>{{part.ordered_from}}</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" ng-change="change(ordered, {{part.id}}, {{part.vehicle_id}}, {{part.ordered_from}})"
        ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-model="ordered" name="part-ordered" >
    <li>
</ul>

<script>
$scope.change = function(value, id, vehicle_id, ordered_from) {
    if (!angular.isDefined(ordered_from)) {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the angular way would be to use a directive something like:

```
<input type="checkbox"  ng-model="part" name="part-ordered" my-popup >
```

Then in your directive you can watch the model :

```
app.directive('myPopup', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function($scope, elem, attr) {
      $scope.$watch(attr.ngModel, function(newVal, oldVal){
          //if condition then do $('#myModal').modal('show');  
          //you could provide a template that is the modal even then do $(element).modal('show')

      });
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, there is a more elegant solution

Check [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

Just add the property into your HTML

```
<div id="myModal" ng-if=modalControl></div>
```

and modify it when you want to show/hide it, in your $scope